# QT MySql connectivity using Windows XP, Qt Creator 4.5.2(windows 32 bit)

Tags: mysql, qt, database-connectivity

Platform:

- Windows XP
- Qt Creator IDE 4.5.2

MySQL is setup here as well.

I want to establish database connection with Qt and MySQL. The following line

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

generates error like below:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC
```

It seems QMYSQL driver is absent here.
What to do?

Comment: I recommend reading the following excellent guide: http://christopher.rasch-olsen.no/2009/04/14/qt-45-and-mysql-plugin-with-mingw-on-windows-xp/ (with comments) - it helped me to solve exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build the Qt/MySQL driver. See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows).

Comment: Hello Lukas, I was too new to understand that I had to open the visual studio command prompt, nmake worked fine and it produced qsqlmysql4.dll.

Comment: Now I copied the qsqlmysql4.dll to %QtCreatorinstallationDir%\qt\plugins\sqldrivers. And the above code shows above errors still. How to let QtCreator recognize the qsqlmysql4.dll ?

Comment: Is `libmysql.dll` somewhere where `qsqlmysql4.dll` can find it?

Comment: Hello Lukas, no libmysql.dll is not there at all. qsqlmysql4.dll is in C:\qt-win-opensource-src-4.5.2\plugins\sqldrivers. And the C:\qt-win-opensource-src-4.5.2 directory does not contain libmysql.dll.

Comment: Hi Lukas, I just found libmysql.dll in C:\mysql-5.1.39-win32\lib\opt. What to do now ?

Comment: Copy it to the application directory, or somewhere to `%PATH%`.

Comment: the link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

The output in my pc as instructed in the [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows) is:

*C:>cd C:\qt-win-opensource-src-4.5.2\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql

C:\qt-win-opensource-src-4.5.2\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake -o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\mysql-5.1.39-win32\include" "LIBS+=C:\mysql-5.1.39-win32\lib\opt\LIBMYSQL.LIB" mysql.pro

C:\qt-win-opensource-src-4.5.2\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\nmake"

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Debug all
```

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189
```

-DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FRO
M_ASCII -DQT_DLL -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I".
.......\include\QtCore" -I"........\include\QtSql" -I"........\include"
 -I"c:\mysql-5.1.39-win32\include" -I"........\include\ActiveQt" -I"tmp\moc\d
ebug_shared" -I"........\mkspecs\win32-msvc2005" -Fotmp\obj\debug_shared\ @C:
\DOCUME~1\test\LOCALS~1\Temp\nm38.tmp

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\c
l.EXE"' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\n
make.exe"' : return code '0x2'*

What might be the problem? Is it the nmake or something else? I did go through the web but I'm stuck here.

Comment: I suggest to use Qt Sdk which comes with Mingw.

Comment: As http://www.rag.com.au/linux/qt4howto.html says after executing the command "configure -platform win32-g++ -static -release -qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-mysql -l mysql -I c:\mysql\include -L c:\mysql\lib\opt" got the error message
"copy qmake.exe D:\Qt\qt\bin\qmake.exe
        1 file(s) copied.
Creating makefiles in src...
Generating Makefiles...
execute: Unknown error
   (-spec)
   (win32-g++)
   (-r)
   (D:/Qt/qt/projects.pro)
   (-o)
   (D:/Qt/qt)
Qmake failed, return code -1"
so can't execute the next command "mingw32-make"
Whan went wrong actually ?

Comment: Anyway, from Qt command prompt "D:\Qt\qt\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>configure -release -qt-sql-mysql -l mysql -I c:\mysql\include -L c:\mysql\lib\opt" executes without any error. Also "mingw32-make" works fine and produces qsqlmysql4.dll & libqsqlmysql4.a in "D:\Qt\qt\plugins\sqldrivers". I thought it was over!!! But still qDebug()<<QSqlDatabase::drivers() shows ("QSQLITE", "QODBC3", "QODBC") no mysql driver :( [I build the project in release mode as produced dll was qsqlmysql4.dll not qsqlmysqld4.dll]... What went wrong ?

Comment: The link is dead now