# Qt 4.8.0 - MySQL Driver not listed

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, driver

After reading this tutorial http://www.pikopong.com/blog/2011/07/11/how-to-enable-mysql-support-in-qt-sdk-for-windows-part-2/ I was able to successfully built the mysql lib for Qt. But somehow it is not listed in the available drivers list, although I copied the files in the right directory.

This is how my Qt-plugins\sqldrivers directory looks like now :

C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\plugins\sqldrivers

- libqsqlite4.a
- libqsqlited4.a
- libqsqlmysql4.a
- libqsqlmysqld4.a
- libqsqlodbc4.a
- libqsqlodbcd4.a
- qsqlite4.dll
- qsqlited4.dll
- qsqlmysql4.dll
- qsqlmysqld4.dll
- qsqlodbc4.dll
- qsqlodbcd4.dll

And this is what QSqlDatabase::drivers() say :

> ("QSQLITE", "QODBC3", "QODBC")

Is there something essential missing?
Thank you for your help in advance and happy holidays!

Comment: I think you should configure mysql's support just before compiling Qt.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530282/qt-mysql-connectivity-using-windows-xp-qt-creator-4-5-2windows-32-bit.  Not sure if you have `ldd` tool but you might want to check if the required mysql libraries are in the path.

Comment: Is the mysql.dll in path or next to qsqlmysql.dll?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Karlson you where right, I followed the steps in your link, now it works.

Comment: Please, answer your question, so you can check it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by following the instructions in this guide:
http://christopher.rasch-olsen.no/2009/04/14/qt-45-and-mysql-plugin-with-mingw-on-windows-xp/
This was posted as a solution to the same problem (See Karlson's comment)